# Java xtend funny compile error : This expression is not allowed in this context, since it doesn't cause any side effects

Tags: java, xtend

I have an error that does not make sense: `This expression is not allowed in this context, since it doesn't cause any side effects.` Here is the scenario in which the compile error is risen.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if(!validationMustReturnTrue()){
         continue; // this line is mark in error
    }
}
```

It is a simple `for` in which I want to skip to the next `result` on a certain condition.

**What does that error mean?**

**And how do you `continue` to next value in Xtend?** found this group discussion on the continue question. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xtend-lang/A8YV2JMeodk. `continue` is not supported in Xtend, but what does the error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `continue` does not change control flow. There is no code that it would prevent from executing.

Try adding some statements after `if` inside the loop and see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Xtend does not support a continue expression. You have to extract that logic into an own method which will improve readability, too. The error about `no side effect` is probably a bug since your continue is detected as a field access which isn't reasonable on its own. You could hover over the error in the left gutter to see other problems at that very same location.